# Are some tango apps on play toxic for the tango tablet?

Tags: google-project-tango

So I was going to do a demo.  And I figured, since my stuff melts down into slag on a regular basis, I'd install all the Tango demo apps.
***Bad idea***
When Tango went to reboot, it went through the normal screen animations, but it hung on the animated tango spinner for over an hour - something was making it hiccup, the spinner was jerky, freezing for a second on pretty much every face.
Did a full data purge, let teh goog reload everything, problem came right back -

> Sorry cap'n, she canna boot.

Did it again, told play to keeps its opinions to itself and not restore anything - just put the explorer and area manager on manually -  great joy, they work fine, things are back to as normal as they get

So, I have a suspicion that some of the demos may work on the phone but lead to some nastiness on the tablet - has anyone else got any experience with or knowledge about this ?

Comment: Have you tried to force shut down and start again the device? and do you remember which app you installed caused this?

Comment: If I knew which app I would say -  I can't fund researching other bad apps, mine is bad enough to eat all my resources  :-)    I agree it would be nice to winnow it down, I can say it is not the Tango Explorer, the Area Manager, or the Room Explorer - its one of the others - I can say I know I pulled them all down.

Comment: And yes, I forced a shutdown -  hey, this is Tango - it used to be that half my attempts to do pointclouds in java ended in a forced shutdown hoping that would fix lack of point cloud data - and then I began to understand poses with respect to the two basis, the startup inertial frame and the area definition frame and pointclouds are far more friendly :-)

Answer (score 0):

To solve the hanging on start up issue, you could hold the power button for 10 seconds to force shut down the device and restart it after.

Comment: Oh, no - trust me - did that - it took holding power, both volume down, going to the magic menu, blowing away ALL the user data, and then preventing the evil little buggers from coming back down - anything else and it hung post the project tango splash, where the logo does its final spinning and you can see it pause very briefly - in this case it paused not briefly on every damn face and this was allowed to go on for hours (once)  I wonder if it was the debugger addin ?  But trust me, it was stuck somewhere bad